# Wpf app in VS2017

Tags: wpf

I'm adding manually a click event in main window of mainwindow.xaml. There are no faults in xaml editor and the button is visible. 
    When switching back to the mainwindow.xaml.cs my click event is NOT automatically added. It goes for all events. These events should be automatically added in the .cs editor along the lines of:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventsArg e)
{

}
```

Any ideas, pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually adding"?  Are you double-clicking the designer? Are you typing a name into the event in properties?

Comment: I mean typing the xaml editor versus using the drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Drag and dropping and the adding the even doesn't work either. Is there some setting somewhere, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If by "adding manually an click event" you mean manually typing in the XAML in the editor then no it does not add it for you at that point.

If IntelliSense is working for you, as you type in the Click="" text, it should popup a menu listing the already available click handlers that you can select AND at the top of that list should be a choice labelled "<New Event Handler>". If you select "<New Event Handler>" it will add it in for you at that time.

[image]

If you don't choose anything from the list but instead just type it in, it is not added. However, at that point, at least for Button controls, you can double-click the button control in the XAML Designer and it will add the click handler into the .xaml.cs code and take you to it.